# Facebook website link Preview image does not available in Website page

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My question is about Facebook link share. I was going through fb page of one of indian language website , There they have shared one link which produced one image ( screenshot is attached). I clicked and surprised to see that the image shown in fb page is no where in website page.

When i inspect element, I cpould see that image is loaded from [Some Safe Image](https://external-sin1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQCzmwommwOWFrwn&w=470&h=246&url=https%3A%2F%2Ffbcdn-sphotos-d-a.akamaihd.net%2Fhphotos-ak-xtp1%2Fv%2Ft1.0-9%2Fs720x720%2F11253636_886890708055560_3422844151368618978_n.jpg%3Foh%3D3a46aa138f946e99540aa1922965b9a0%26oe%3D564A6471%26__gda__%3D1446593766_4a9e2e7723f55d8c4accd08baa81f47c&cfs=1&upscale=1)

How they managed to do it.?
WHat is this safe image, which loaded in fb page but no where present in website page.[image]

Website post url is : [this](http://bit.ly/1VRlH2g)

Facebook Page Url is : [this](https://www.facebook.com/udayavani.webnews)

Comment: maybe this way?
http://www.socialmediaexaminer.com/embedded-facebook-posts/

Comment: They probably have specified a `<meta property="og:image" content="…"/>` tag in their `<head>`. Well, they have, but it’s a different image. That’s how you would normally do it, though. Specify an image with this tag and then share your site; the specified picture should show up then.

Answer (score 0):

According to [facebook's debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fbit.ly%2F1VRlH2g) the image was changed 2 hours ago, as Xufor said you do not need the image on the page -  only the `og:image` meta tag needs to point to it.

You use the debugger to re-scrape (re-fetch)  the page each time the image changes. It you share it again on facebook you will see the new image instead, in a smaller size.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.udayavani.com/sites/default/files/images/articles/2015/07/30/katrina-kaif-wallpaper-138-.jpg" />
```

[image]